# Error while setting the path for download headers of an Excel file

Tags: php, header

I have the following code:

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($excel);    
$objWriter->save("uploads/".$excel_file);
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="uploads/'.$excel_file.'"');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

The file is indeed in the "uploads" directory, but I fail to link it correctly in this line of code: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="uploads/'.$excel_file.'"');`

Any idea about how should I set the path in order to download the correct file?

Thanks.

Comment: That header is telling the browser what filename to save the file as by default, not which file to send to the browser.

Comment: And can I set header() to send to the browser the file in uploads directory?

Comment: No, you have to send the right file to the browser, probably using [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile).

Answer (score 0):

Replace that line with

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=uploads/".$excel_file.";");
```

And at last, add following lines

```
readfile($excel_file);
exit;
```